# discord.js creating a role with permissions

Tags: javascript, discord.js

how can i make the bot create a role with specific permissions? (in this case it has to set SEND_MESSAGES to disabled), this is the code i made:

```
var muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Muted");

if (!muteRole) message.guild.roles.create(

            { data: { name: 'Muted', reason: 'the role is needed', permissions: ["SEND_MESSAGES" = false]} });
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create the role first, then modify the permissions, this cannot be done in one function call. Here's how you can do it:

```js
var muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Muted");

if (!muteRole) message.guild.roles.create({
  data: {
    name: 'Muted',
    reason: 'the role is needed'
  }
})
.then(role => role.setPermissions(["ANY_PERMISSION_HERE"])
.catch(error => /* catch error (optional) */);
```

Or if you want, you can use JavaScript's `async/await` API:

```js
try {
  var muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Muted");

  if (!muteRole) muteRole = await message.guild.roles.create({
    data: {
      name: 'Muted',
      reason: 'the role is needed'
    }
  });

  muteRole.setPermissions(["YOUR_PERMISSIONS"]);
} catch (error) {
  // catch the error (optional)
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. You can set the permissions in a single step as you can pass an array of permissions to a [`RoleData`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/RoleData). OP actually wants the role NOT to have the `SEND_MESSAGES` permission which doesn't make any sense as (by not setting it) it doesn't have it by default. Look at their example, they try to set it to false...

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros yes, that is why you have to do it in 2 functions